# Why is the output of an async function printed before that function is called?

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, sleep

The behavior of async functions is different even though they are almost the same code, but I don't understand why.

My code is:

```
import asyncio

async def func1():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("func1")

async def func2():
    await asyncio.sleep(time)
    print("func2")

async def func3():
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print("func3")

async def main():
    asyncio.create_task(func1())
    await func2()
    await func3()

asyncio.run(main())
```

If I put `time = 1` then the output is:

```
func2

func1

func3
```

But if `time = 2` then the output is:

```
func1

func2

func3
```

In the first case, why is `func2` printed before `func1` even though func2 starts late?

Comment: Is `func2` supposed to have a `time` parameter?

Comment: Nope, it is just a placeholder for numerical values

Comment: Where does `func2` get `time` in `await asyncio.sleep(time)`? I'm trying to get it to be complete runnable example. I also edited to update your tags, your formatting, and your title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter how you get `time` into `func2`, the difference is clearly between how you start `func1` and `func2`:

```
async def main():
    asyncio.create_task(func1())
    await func2()
    ...
```

You create the task, and then instantly await `func2`. Then, when `func2` goes to sleep, `func1` has a chance to start, and also goes to sleep.

If `func2` finds that `time == 1`, it wakes up after one second and prints, and then after that `func1` wakes up, just a fraction later.

If `func2` finds that `time == 2`, it only wakes up after two seconds, and `func1` will have woken up before it.

Your question was "In the first case, why is func2 printed before func1 even though func2 starts late?" - you assume `func2` "starts late", but it doesn't. It is awaited before the task created with `func1`. You never explicitly await the task, and your program could complete without the task ever completing, but since you have `func3` there, waiting substantially longer, you're almost guaranteed it will.

You would have found the order doesn't change when you do this:

```
async def main():
    await func1()
    await func2()
    ...
```

Because then the two asynchronous functions are awaited in order, and will complete in order when provided with the same `sleep()` time.

Similarly, with:

```
async def main():
    t = asyncio.create_task(func1())
    await t
    await func2()
    ...
```

The order is as you expect it, since the task is explicitly awaited before `func2()` is started and awaited.

Or of course, just:

```
async def main():
    await asyncio.create_task(func1())
    await func2()
    ...
```

A good editor or IDE will warn you, if you don't await `create_task`. PyCharm warns: "Co-routine create_task is not awaited".

[The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#creating-tasks) has this to say: "Important: Save a reference to the result of this function, to avoid a task disappearing mid-execution. The event loop only keeps weak references to tasks. A task that isn’t referenced elsewhere may get garbage collected at any time, even before it’s done. For reliable “fire-and-forget” background tasks, gather them in a collection."

Comment: Good explanation. FWIW, this type of issue is one of the reasons I no longer use Python if I can avoid it. And it pains me to say that since it was my favorite non-compiled (you know what I mean) language for nearly a decade. These days I'm more likely to just use Go since it compiles fast, has a much saner concurrent execution mechanism (goroutines), has excellent tooling, and is just generally a superior language to Python.

Comment: @KurtisRader Actually, the OP's original title was "_Why are there different outputs_". I [edited it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78206954/revisions) to become "_Why is the output of an async function printed before that function is called?_" because that's how I read the OP's confusion. If someone has a better title, feel free to edit it.

Comment: @GinoMempin, It appears to me you should not have edited their summary line. Their original title makes more sense. Your rewrite implies, to a native English speaker, that they were surprised that some of the output occurred before the relevant function was run. People unfamiliar with how concurrency behaves often make such mistakes. Their original title reflects their misunderstanding of how concurrency works. Please don't muddy the waters.

Comment: @KurtisRader please restrict your comments to the content of the answer, or to provide additions and corrections. Your opinion on what programming languages you find preferable, or what others may be thinking, is not relevant here. To the factuality of your comment: any language with asynchronicity and grouped management of co-routines will have similar examples. OP was simply wondering why the two ways of starting an asynchronous method are not equivalent, something I hope my answer clarifies.